Org table fonts
On org tables I had Courier font and that looked very nice. (My general font is Monaco)
Today while installing something else, for some reason, Brew installed a new version of Emacs and some of my settings changed.
Following this answer, I added this line
(set-face-attribute 'fixed-pitch nil :font "Courier")

to my .emacs but this did not change the table font, I still see Monaco.
Any ideas how I can fix this?

AFAICT, org-table does not inherit from any other face (that might have changed recently: I'm not sure). You might want to try this:
(set-face-attribute 'org-table nil :inherit 'fixed-pitch)

in addition to what you show above. Untested.
EDIT: source blocks (and example blocks) use face org-block, so all you should have to do to have them rendered in Courier is to have that face inherit from fixed-pitch as well:
(set-face-attribute 'org-block nil :inherit 'fixed-pitch)

You can find out which face is used for a particular character with C-u C-x =. You'll get a display that includes the following:
...
There are text properties here:
  face                 (org-block)
...

or if there are multiple faces, it would say something like this:
...
There are text properties here:
  face                 (font-lock-keyword-face org-block)
...

That's how you find out which face(s) a particular character has.

Great, thanks! This worked. src font, like, #+begin_src sqrt(42) #+end_src or text between the equal signs, used to be Courier too. Do you know how can I change that back to Courier as well? Thanks again

See edited answer.
